# Looking for jQuery script to swap div contents depending on checkbox checked/unchecked

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, swap

I'm looking for a quick script to change a div when a checkbox is checked.

**For example:** Check the checkbox and "div1" appears. Uncheck the checkbox and "div2" appears.

**Visual example:** http://www.mmo-champion.com/ Take a look at there "Recent Forum Posts" box. I'm looking for something exactly like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please see the code below:

```
$("#cbox").click(function() {
   if ( $(this).is(':checked') )
   {
     $("#div1").show();
     $("#div2").hide();
   }
   else
   {
     $("#div1").hide();
     $("#div2").show();
   }    
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Now is there a way to save the users option in there cookies? So that when they revisit the page the checkbox remains the same?

Comment: Hmm, the code doesn't seem to work in IE. There a work around for that?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work on my IE8, odd. My CMS uses prototype so I had to change all the $'s to "jQuery" could that cause anything? Also, do you know anything about cookies? I'd like to set this up so that the div and checkbox the user leaves it at remains the same upon page reload.

Comment: Fixed the IE 8 issue, just had to update jQuery. Still seeking help for the cookies though! =)

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
$('#checkboxID').click(
    function(){
        $('#div1, #div2').toggle();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yHTFF/1/)

This assumes that the `div1` is hidden, and `div2` is shown, on page-load and the first click will check the checkbox and therefore show the `div`s.

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).